# Difference between Task.Start and using discard

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a Task that does not return a result, and no other code is dependent on it completing, like this:

```
private async Task PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken CancellationToken)
{
    bool IsComplete = false;
    while (!IsComplete && !CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Do stuff until Complete or Cancelled
    }
}
```

I have be using the discard to run it, like this:

```
_ = PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken);
```

which works OK, but recently I discovered Task.Start.  I know using Task.Start gives me the option of monitoring the task (if I store the result), but in this case, is there any difference between discard and this?

```
PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken).Start();
```

Is it better practice to use discard as it's the newer feature?

Comment: I think both aren't optimal, as you're not catching any exception. I would issue a `Task.Run(async () => { try{ await PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken);} catch { /*handling */}});`

Comment: @JHBonarius "optimal" is contextual; for most definitions, the "optimal" thing would be for `PerformMyTaskAsync` to handle the fault internally, so we don't need to add a wrapper layer

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah, `optimal` was a bad choice of words, as it insinuates my solution is optimal, which it isn't. Redarding the second thing: I've learned the hard way not to trust the called async method to handle all exceptions properly. "Swallowed" exceptions have caused much headaches. `Nito.AsyncEx` probably has some nice solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken).Start()` doesn't do what you want, so: don't do that! `PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken)` will return an *initialized working operation* - it has already been started, because *you just did that* - calling `.Start()` will throw `InvalidOperationException` citing "Start may not be called on a promise-style task".

Discard itself *doesn't do anything* except tell the compiler "I meant to do this", which is basically just a way of saying "I don't want to await this" to suppress a compiler warning (CS4014 "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."). You can do that with the result of `Task.Run`, too - and should do in exactly the same scenarios.

So the real question here is `Task.Run` vs direct invoke; for *that*, the main difference is "how much of it runs *now*?". When invoking it directly, it will run on the current thread *until the first incomplete `await`* - at which point the async machinery kicks in. That can mean it runs *to completion*, and with a `while` loop could mean it effectively runs forever (for example if the loop incorrectly uses `Thread.Sleep()` instead of `Task.Delay()` for pausing). If you don't want *any* of it to run on the current thread, or you want it to be very clear that this is a parallel execution: use `Task.Run`:

```cs
_ = Task.Run(() => PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.  I didn't realise the discard could still block.  So is this the correct call:  Task.Run(()=> PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken));

Comment: @JonRoberts discard will not block its same like the call without discard `connector.GetCongestionTaxRules(cityRequestRouteValue);` it will just suppress the compiler warning.

Comment: @JonRoberts I'd probably use `Task.Run` unless I was absolutely certain what was happening inside, and that it would go async promptly (perhaps by using `await Task.Yield();` on the first line)

Comment: +1 for the answer, -1 for the comment that suggests using `await Task.Yield()` for the purpose of offloading. This is not its intended purpose, and it's not doing it reliably. For offloading work to the `ThreadPool`, use the `Task.Run` method. It exists for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I never said anything about offloading *to the thread-pool* specifically (I'm very aware of sync-context) - simply ensuring that it forces an async interruption to make the method complete asynchronously, which *is* what it achieves; if you have specific objections to `Task.Yield()`, I'd love to hear them

Comment: I object to `await Task.Yield()` when used for the purpose of offloading. Since you say that you are not suggesting it for this purpose, I would like to read the exact reason that you are suggesting it for, before arguing further against it. "*go async promptly*" / *"make the method complete asynchronously"* is too vague. Please describe a specific situation where you would use `await Task.Yield()`, explaining what's the problem, and how the `await Task.Yield()` would solve it. You could edit the answer and add the explanation inside, so that it can be evaluated (voted) by the community.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias but *why* do you object to that? My clarification earlier was because you mentioned the `ThreadPool`, which yield doesn't guarantee. I agree Task.Run is more explicit and I tend to prefer it - I'm just intrigued as to your depth of feeling here. And I'm curious. A lot of strong opinions are essential the coding equivalent of PTSD from bad experiences, so if you have horror stories: I'd love to hear them! I'm not trying to be dismissive - quite the opposite.

Comment: Marc I do have horror stories I could share, with coworkers giving misleading names to database entities, like naming apples "oranges", and oranges "apples". Which is pretty horrifying, if you have to deal with it in a daily basis. Seeing tools used incorrectly for a purpose that they are not intended to fulfill is less torturing, but still worthy of a downvote. If you want to switch to the `ThreadPool` imperatively, install the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading package and do `await TaskScheduler.Default.SwitchTo()`. Don't misuse the `Task.Yield`. Even better, stick with the `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `_ = PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken);` and `var task = PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken);` are identical, the only difference is that `_` (discard) suppresses the warning because it is not awaited if you use `PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken);`.

You do not need `PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken).Start();` to call an asynchronous method. Task is already started when you call the method. If you do not want to store the result ( awaitable task), you can simply use `PerformMyTaskAsync(CancellationToken);`